# How to create rounded corners on WiFi signal shape in Adobe Illustator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to recreate my logo in AI. I do not know how to achieve arched WiFi signal vector shape with rounded corners.

[image: rounded wifi vector signal]

What I tried:

1. I tried to use rounded rectangle + warp arch effect. This effect gave me banana type corners which are not perfectly rounded
2. I tried to use rectangle tool with straight edges + warp arch effect. After that I did this Effect → Stylize → Rounded corners but it won't to apply for some reasons, probably because path is not touching the edges anymore
3. I tried following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBQ4vC7E6KA) and tried to apply rounded corners, but I I failed again

I am pretty newbie in AI and I found it very difficult to handle. I am asking myself why did they have to reinvent the wheel when Photoshop was already easy and straightforward. From applying blending options to everything else it is, so damn user unfriendly.

Is there any easy way for this?

Answer (score 3):

Make a thick line with the pen and change the cap style to rounded:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The shape can be drawn with three stroked lines (I used the Ellipse tool and cut to size). To get the rounding all you have to do is apply rounded caps on the stroke.

[image: Illustrator stroke options]

[image: WiFi Symbol]